# Testing Ember without explicit `Ember.run`

Tags: ember.js

If `transitionTo` is not wrapped in `Ember.run`, tests will fail due to the absence of the run-loop's autorun.

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    actionName: function() {
      var router = this.get('target');

      setTimeout(function() {
        // I want to get rid of this `Ember.run` wrapper, and just use
        // `router.transitionTo('index');`
        Ember.run(function() {
          router.transitionTo('index');
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Is there a way to get rid of `Ember.run` in testing mode?

Thanks!

#### ** Update **

Sorry, left out the most important thing: the problem is only present when some async task is going on and `Ember.run` is left out in testing mode. Updated the example with a `setTimeout`.

Comment: This is strange, if you are using the ember test api.http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/integration/, that runloop stuff is abstracted from the user. Can you share the code where the test call this action?

Answer (score 2):

When testing ember apps you normally set `Ember.testing = true` this will disable the automatic runloop, which gives you the control to manually schedule asynchronous operations to happen in a one-off runloop via `Ember.run`

`Ember.run` is therefore obligatory otherwise you get race conditions because your code will not run syncronized with other tasks ember is doing under the hood.

So I guess you are better off using the `Ember.run` wrapper.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for responding! I understand the concept, but doesn't this ruin the whole concept of autorun? I mean since I can't rely on it if I want my code to be tested, what's the point of having autorun in the first place?